# How do I setup 1 to 1 NAT in google cloud?

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform, ipv4

I am new to google cloud,

I have been able to setup 1-to-many NAT but need to setup 1-to-1 NAT in google cloud? How do I do this!??! I cannot find the proper documentation, or figure out ... What steps do I need to do to assign an external ip, to an internal ip, and setup the internal ip.s etc. for a single vm.

Answer (score 0):

Google Compute Engine does not provide a service that offers 1:1 NAT so you'd have to build this yourself.

Comment: This is not Google compute engine, but rather the Google cloud engine, networking specific.

Comment: There is no "Google cloud engine". There's GCP (the entire platform) comprising GCE (the IaaS portion), GAE (the PaaS portion), GKE (containers), GCS (object storage) and so on. You would have to build this on GCE.